# How do I find the location of files deployed as part of a ClickOnce Application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, clickonce

For example I can use:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

to Find the location of the files released when I debug.
Is there anything similar to find the location of the deployed files after they have been installed.

Comment: What makes you think it won't work once deployed? Did you test it and got wrong results?

Comment: Yes it should work - it works for me. :)

Comment: I'm not trying to find the executing assembly.  I am deploying the app with a batchfile and I want to copy it to the start menu.  The code I gave gets the location of the execution application file that's located in the release folder after I publish.  Do you know How I can do this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking.  Do you want to create a setup program that adds an icon for your program in the Start menu?

Comment: No GTG.  Long story short I'm making an app with a database and a synchronization server running.  So I need this batch file which I deploy to be in the start menu along with the application executable.  Do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

The application executable is not "put in the start menu". ClickOnce apps put a shortcut in the start menu that invokes the deployment url and basically runs the application. So you wouldn't put a batch file in the start menu per se, you would put a shortcut to the batch file in the start menu. To find the start menu of a ClickOnce application, try something like this:

```
string startMenuFolder = string.Concat(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs),
                    "\\", publisher_name);
```

where the publisher_name is what you've filled in for Publisher Name in the Publish properties. if you've filled in the suite, you need to put that in there, too.